# How to make switch in iOS greyscale, not blue?

Tags: objective-c, ios, colors, grayscale

I want to make my switches show in B&W mode instead of default blueish. 
The same effect is present in Camera app. There switches in Options view are also in greyscale mode. 
Is it easy to do or it needs subclassing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS 5's appearance API allows you to set, among other things, a color scheme for your UIKit controls. For switches, you set the `onTintColor` property:

```
[[UISwitch appearance] setOnTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```

If you need to support earlier versions of iOS, however, you'll have to design and implement your own custom switch control.

Comment: And it will affect all Switches in my application, right? Is it possible to do the same for particular switch?

Comment: @BartoNaz: Of course, just set it for whatever switch object you have in your application's view: `[aSwitch setOnTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];` The `[UISwitch appearance]` is for the appearance proxy, which affects all switches.